# Missing departmentNumber from ldap using PHP

Tags: php, ldap

This is my setting:

```
$base_dn = 'OU=Users,OU=MYCOMPANY_COM,DC=MYCOMPANY,DC=LOCAL';
$ldap_postfix = '@MYCOMPANY.LOCAL';
ldap_set_option($this->conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($this->conn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
$search_filter = '(&(objectCategory=*)(objectClass=*)(SAMAccountName=' . $username . '*))';
```

Mu ldap is on Microsoft ActiveDirectory.
It works well and I get all parameters of requested username from ldap except info about department.
What am I dooing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I found the problem.
It was due at AD was department empty. After this attribute was filled ldap return it.
Simple and stupid.